# confused about struct an class with same name

Tags: c++, class, struct, header

I'm reviewing some c++ code and facing an issue I don't understand.
I have multiple cpp files, a `main.cpp` with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classtest.h"
#include "test2.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
foo test;
test.b=5;
...
```

Look at the includes, `test2.h` is empty, and `test2.cpp` contain just this:

```
struct foo{
    int a;
};
```

The other header included, `classtest.h` contains this:

```
using namespace std;

class foo{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

As you can see there is a class and struct with the same name. My question is: why type `foo` in my main method is the struct and not the class? It is not defined in the header `test2.h`, how can `main` access it? Second question: given `foo` is the struct (I'm using eclipse and see it positioning mouse cursor on it), how can be accessible the field `b`, that doesn't exist for the struct?
Sorry but I'm quite newbie in c++, I need to clarify this doubt. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why type foo in my main method is the struct and not the class?

It is not the `foo` that was defined in `test2.cpp`. You include the defnition from `classtest.h`, so that is what is used in `main`.

> It is not defined in the header test2.h, how can main access it?

It doesn't, and it can not access a definition that is not included.

> Second question: given foo is the struct

This premise is wrong.

> how can be accessible the field b, that doesn't exist for the struct?

Because, as we have concluded, `foo` is the one that was defined in `classtest.h`.

---

Note, that if you would link together the object files from both `main.cpp` and `test2.cpp`, there would be two conflicting definitions for `foo`. Therefore the program would be violating the [one definition rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) and it would be [ill-formed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: Your last statement point in the right direction I think.. If I understand creating the executable of this project I'll have two conflicting global definition of foo, leading to unpredictable behaviour. Right? Last ... why eclipse show the struct definition highlighting foo in main.cpp ? Is that a bug or something else?

Comment: @rok Perhaps eclipse simply selected one of the conflicting definitions at random. The static analyzer of eclipse is by no means perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from `#include <iostream>`, if you substitute the `#include`s manually, you end up with this for `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class foo{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};
using namespace std;
int main() {
foo test;
test.b=5;
```

Hence it's abundantly clear that `foo` is the `class`. There's nothing fishy going on here at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the `class foo` from `classtest.h`, not from `test2.cpp`. In C++, there is no difference between a `class` and a `struct` apart from the default member access (`public` for `struct,`private`for`class`).

That's why you have the member `b` in your instance of `foo`. The reason the code compiles and links fine is because both `foo`s are not defined at the same time. Only one is defined per translation unit.